# Eclipse Mars for Salesforce development?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Kepler for Salesforce development as recommended here https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation. 
I wonder if I can use later versions of Eclipse. If yes, is it worth upgrading?

Comment: Are you coming from a Java eclipse background? If you are teaching yourself Apex and have never used Eclipse I would check out MavensMate. This is fast becoming the most popular IDE. I'm sure some people will disagree with that.

Comment: @MichaelGill - If they do disagree well then they are just disagreeable people lol.....For a non Java background person there is nothing I could find that Eclipse could do over Mavensmate. OP - MavensMate and Sublime - Best combo going at this point. Although there is a native SF IDE, link, hmmm, https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5SYEEA3 - Has a lot of promise.....Also http://aside.io

Comment: Lol. I love aside.io when not on my own machine or I can't refresh my local metadata

Comment: @MichaelGill - One thing is for sure, the SF Dev console is just as bad. I wish SF would work with J. Ferraro and Uwe Helm to work on a much better Dev experience......It to be soon good if they would put effort into development instead of just adding stuff to it...But I digress

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at MavensMate with Sublime. I've been using Eclipse Kepler for two months. It gets the job done but there are things which could be improved. I guess I'll have to experiment with Eclipse Mars and see for myself.

Comment: The big thing for me is speed. I previously used Eclipse one hell of lot. For NetSuite, Talend and Salesforce. It's robust, but slow as...

Comment: I'm trying it out. User experience is great but talking about speed, it seems that save time to server is longer than in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently using Mars and everything works great! I *am* having an issue with running tests inside Eclipse, but running tests from the Setup menu online is okay.

I integrate with Git as well and use Ant for running the Migration Tool all from inside Eclipse. Team Synchronizing also works well.

I encourage you to give it a try.

Go to:  Help -> Install New Software... -> Add...

Use:  http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that I have had trouble with Mars. I can not even get the package to install any longer. I never really used the IDE personally, except to be able to export and back up my work. If you are looking for something nice to look at, I can't recommend CodeFusion by elastify enough. I am not affiliated with them, however, I did review on their page, I say that to say, look in the response from the developer, he gave an updated version download in his response, and it's smooth as butter, and really easy on the eyes. Page --> https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5SYEEA3

Newer version (v2.1024) here:

https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t20000000Hnpx (DE+Production)

https://test.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t20000000Hnpx (Sandboxes)

It would be great if this could get some love from the community, it is a beautiful product and personally I would love to see it stick around for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing issues in installing the force.com IDE plugin in eclipse mars. When i tried to install it then i am getting below errors:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=D__softwares_Eclipse_eclipse-jee-mars_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/plugins/com.salesforce.ide.apex.core_35.0.0.201510211056.jar.
Connection reset
Unable to read repository at http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/plugins/com.salesforce.ide.core_35.0.0.201510211056.jar.
Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 15819714; received: 4971501
```

I even tried to install an older version of the force.com IDE plugin, then also same issue is coming.